# Java threads stress test

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to run a small test on the maximum number of concurrent threads I could run on a single JVM and the time it takes to create a large number of threads. I have the following trivial code

```
public class Threading {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                ;
        }
    };

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        new Thread(task).start();

    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
     System.out.printf("Time for task to complete: %.2f seconds", (double) time / 1000000000.0);
 }
}
```

I am using VisualVM to track the number of active threads.

The results I am getting seem odd. The peak active threads I am reaching is around 100 and the average number of active threads is around 15. and It's taking more than 60 seconds for the 1 million threads to be created.

[image: VisualVM Screenshot]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting from 0 to 100000 without doing anything else is so fast (and is even probably removed completely by Hotspot, reducing the `run()` method to a noop) that you'll never have a large number of concurrent threads: it takes more time to start a new thread than it takes for threads to complete and die.

Why don't you make all your threads sleep forever? That would guarantee that they're all started.

Comment: I want the threads to be active doing some work because I want to test the effect of context switching. I tried giving the threads some actual work to do, but that didn't change the number of active threads. It's just taking more time to finish now.

Comment: If you want to test the impact of context switching, you'd better start a reasonable number of threads (let's say 20) and make them all wait on a CountDownLatch, and then make them do something reasonably complex (like sorting a large array for example). You could then measure the time it takes compared to doing the same thing with two threads (assuming you have 2 cores) doing the same thing 10 times in sequence. That would show you the cost of context switching.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing anything wrong here?

No, I don't think so although it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

The only problem I see is that your work loop is going to finish in *very* little time.  The time your program is taking is mostly going to be spent in `Thread` creation more than anything else.

```
// this is going to take a couple ns at most
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
     ;
```

I'd significantly increase the amount of work each thread is doing to see if that is more like you expected.

Once you increase the amount of work each thread is doing, you will quickly find that you will most likely run out of stack-space memory for the threads or some OS limit long before you are able to fork 1 million of them.

Comment: My objective is to compare multithreading with message passing. I am by the way working on a Mac. java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01-447-11M4203)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01-447, mixed mode)

Comment: In what way are you comparing them?

Comment: Mainly performance. The question I am trying to answer is whether the shift from multithreading to message-passing would affect the performance.